# Tracerout fails in last hop but succeed from last machine

Tags: routing, traceroute

I have 3 servers : A, B and C.

A = 10.1.52.100     subnetMask = 255.255.255.0   defaultGateway = 10.1.51.254
B = 213.56.106.137 subnetMask = 255.255.255.192 defaultGateway = 213.56.106.190
C = 213.56.106.197 subnetMask = 255.255.255.224 defaultGateway = 213.56.106.222

The 3 servers and in different network. C is a linux Machine
From server A, I type this command :

```
tracert B
```

I get this result :

```
1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  10.1.52.254
2    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  10.1.255.254
3     1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  10.1.255.63
4     6 ms     6 ms     7 ms  213.56.106.197
5  213.56.106.197  reports: Destination host unreachable.
```

C is the server with ip 213.56.106.197; from that server if I type the same command :

```
tracert B
```

I get :

```
Traceroute to 213.56.106.137 (213.56.106.137), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  213.56.106.197 (213.56.106.197)  2996.302 ms !H  2996.307 ms !H  2996.300 ms !H
```

Why cannot I reach server B from server A?

Comment: Are both servers using the same DNS servers?

Comment: Looks like incorrect subnet and gateway settings on C.

Comment: thanks you user3767013
i updated the question with details on settings for subnet and gateway.

Comment: Are 213.56.106.190 and 213.56.106.222 assigned to the same machine? It's not clear how this is supposed to work, which makes it very hard to figure out why it's not working.